# Memory problem when filtering an OLAP cube

Tags: excel, vba, olap-cube

So I have a macro that for starters needs to open a file and filter the OLAP cube with some dates. Performing this actions burns a lot of memory, going from 100Mb to 1,5Gb.

That's a problem because later I'm gonna fill with a lot of data my classes and might raise the out of memory error.

The thing is that I can't seem to clear the memory in any way because it is not occupying that bunch because of some store object, just because it is filtering the cube.

Does anyone how to solve this? I've tried saving the workbook, even stoping the macro and saving the workbook won't solve this.

the Main sub:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()

    Dim MisDatos As New España

    MisDatos.CargaReales


End Sub
```

The class doing the work:

```
Option Explicit
Private m_Login As Object
Property Get Logins(ByVal Key As String) As Logins
    With m_Login
        If Not .Exists(Key) Then .Add Key, New Logins
    End With
    Set Logins = m_Login(Key)
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_Login = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_Login = Nothing
End Sub
Public Property Get Keys() As Variant
    Keys = m_Login.Keys
End Property
Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = m_Login.Count
End Property
Public Sub CargaReales()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Adherencia\España\BI KronosReporting.xlsb", False, True)

    Dim ArrayFechasFiltrado As Variant
    ArrayFechasFiltrado = CargaFechasFiltrado
    FiltrarTablaReales wb, ArrayFechasFiltrado
    Erase ArrayFechasFiltrado

    Dim arrReales As Variant
    arrReales = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
    wb.Close False
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
Private Function CargaFechasFiltrado() As Variant

    Dim Festivos As Object
    Set Festivos = CargaFestivos

    'Vamos a cargar las fechas que necesitaremos para cargar los fichajes en un array
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

        Dim FechaI As Date
        FechaI = Left(.Cells(1, 2), 10) 'Fecha Inicio

        Dim FechaF As Date
        FechaF = Right(.Cells(1, 2), 10) 'Fecha Fin

        ReDim arr(Day(FechaI) To Day(FechaF) - Festivos.Count) As String 'Declaramos un array del tamaño de los días necesarios

        Dim Fecha As Date
        Dim i As Long
        Dim x As Long: x = Day(FechaI)
        For i = Day(FechaI) To Day(FechaF) 'hacemos un bucle para meter dichos días en el array
            Fecha = DateSerial(Year(FechaI), Month(FechaI), i)
            If Not Festivos.Exists(Fecha) Then
                arr(x) = "[Fecha Trabajo].[Fecha Trabajo].[Día del Mes].&[" & Format(Fecha, "yyyymmdd") & "]"
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    CargaFechasFiltrado = arr

End Function
Private Function CargaFestivos() As Object

    'Cargamos los festivos en un diccionario
    Dim Diccionario As Object: Set Diccionario = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
        Dim lrow As Long
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        If lrow > 2 Then
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 3 To lrow
                Diccionario.Add .Cells(i, 4).Value, 1
            Next i
            Set CargaFestivos = Diccionario
        Else
            Set CargaFestivos = Nothing
        End If
    End With

End Function
Private Sub FiltrarTablaReales(wb As Workbook, arr As Variant)

    wb.SlicerCaches("SegmentaciónDeDatos_Fecha_Trabajo.Fecha_Trabajo").VisibleSlicerItemsList = arr

End Sub
```

It is the last sub, `FiltrarTablaReales` which is filling the memory. As you can see there are no objects but an array later on emptied(which can't consume that much of memory because it's 1 to 31 at max).

Any thoughts?

Comment: How big is your dataset you are trying to analyze. If you are using 31 columns, and the recordset is huge, this would make sense.

Comment: The dataset is huge @RyanWildry but that's why we are using an OLAP cube, thought I'm only using 7 columns of data.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? And is it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? A database?

Comment: When is CargaReales called? Is it possible this is running multiple times?

Comment: @HackSlash Hi, I'm using 32 bits. Performance is not a problem, my problem is that I don't know why Excel is still having so much memory occupied after even closing the workbook it was filtering from. And the data is from a workbook with an OLAP cube.

Comment: @T4roy it's running only once, the main procedure is calling it.

Comment: What metrics are you using to measure memory usage?

Comment: Hello @SMeaden, I'm watching the task manager. And even after closing the workbook which perfoms this, If I have any other workbook open, the memory is still used.

Comment: Can you do the filtering outside of Excel? Parameterize the OLAP cube query in some way? Shift the problem to the server.

Comment: I finally gave up and wrote a file to do the filtering before this macro starts... So I don't fill that bunch of memory @QHarr

Comment: @Damian Makes sense if possible to shift it out. What do you mean by wrote a file? Sounds interesting. The problem looks interesting but I didn't have the right circumstances to reproduce.

Comment: @QHarr a file with a workbook open event which will run this code and close all workbooks, so the memory gets reseted to work with the already filtered data.

Answer (score 0):

The workbook is being accessed many times when it doesn't have to be. I would try moving the sheet into an array and then dropping the array after.

```
Private Function CargaFestivos() As Object

    'Cargamos los festivos en un diccionario
    Dim Diccionario As Object: Set Diccionario = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
        Dim lrow As Long
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        If lrow > 2 Then
            Dim i As Long
'change here
            dim myArr as variant
            redim myArr(1 to lrow, 1 to 1)
            myArr=.cells(1,4).resize(lrow).value
            For i = 3 To lrow
                Diccionario.Add myArr(i,1), 1 'get it to use the array instead
'end of changes
            Next i
            Set CargaFestivos = Diccionario
        Else
            Set CargaFestivos = Nothing
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Once the array is populated you could even close the workbook.

Comment: Hello Leif, this is no help at all on my topic, but thanks. I don't need to work this inside an array because its going to be max 2-3 cells that I'm gonna be looping thorugh. My problem is with the memory consumption by the OLAP filtering.